# Deleted /usr/bin/docker on CentOs

Tags: linux, bash, centos, docker

I wanted to uninstall docker from my CentOs Machine and run this script :

```
 curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

But it told me that the docker command was already available on the system and it could cause problems if I chose to continue the script. So I deleted /usr/bin/docker but when I ran the script it didn't reinstall /usr/bin/docker. So basically, docker is installed but I can't run it.

I tried to reinstall it with yum but it didn't succeed.
I don't have the docker command in /usr/local/bin/

Comment: Download the appropriate RPM that contains the `/usr/bin/docker`, convert to `.tar.gz` file using alien, extract it, and manually replace the file you manually deleted.  Should you need to remove the installed RPM(s) for docker, do it properly using the `rpm` or `yum` commands as appropriate.

Comment: How do you find the appropriate RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who encouter the same problem : here is the solution :

1) Delete properly docker : `sudo yum remove docker-ce`

2) Download docker rpm : https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/

3) Install alien : `sudo yum install alien`

4) Convert rpm to tgz : `alien --to-tgz package.rpm`

5) Look for the /usr/bin/docker file : `tar -tf package.tgz`

6) Exctract the /usr/bin/docker file : `tar xf package.tgz ./usr/bin/docker`

7) copy to /usr/bin/docker the extracted file

8) test the docker command : `docker -v`

Encountered error :

```
docker: error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Troubleshoot :

```
sudo yum install -y libtool-ltdl
```

Much thanks to ivanivan, hope this post helped